# Game moves faster after weird interaction

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

Im trying to make a game in love2d using Lua where you control some humans and order them to do certain tasks (get Wood, fight etc). The game is supposed to start with 1 human, then add more using resources. The problem is, after I tried adding more using space button to see how they interact, they move faster the more humans I add. Here is the code for spawning, walking and updating:

```
function spawnPeople(x, y)
    local people = world:newRectangleCollider(x, y, 70, 90, {collision_class = 'Player'})
    table.insert(peopleS, people)    

    people:setFixedRotation(true)

    people.direction = d[math.random(1,2)]
    people.speed = 20
end

function walk(dt)
    for i,p in ipairs(peopleS) do

        local px, py = p:getPosition()
            p:setX(px + p.speed * p.direction * dt)

        if IsTimeToProcess(math.random(2)) then
            p.direction = d[math.random(2)]
            p.speed = s[math.random(2)]
        end
        
    end
end

function updatePeople(dt)
    for i,p in ipairs(peopleS) do
        local px, py = p:getPosition()

        local colliders = world:queryRectangleArea(px +(40 * p.direction), py + 40, 10, 10)

        walk(dt)
    end
end
```

I tried printing the speed to see if they stack and the value is unchanged no matter how many humans I add, even tho the game moves faster. Made people.speed into a global variable, nothing. Why is that? Whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Your `walk(dt)` function loops over all people, moving them all. You call this function *for every* person. This means that the more people there are, the more calls the your `walk(dt)`, the larger the distance walked. Just move `walk(dt)` out of the loop:

```lua
function updatePeople(dt)
    for i,p in ipairs(peopleS) do
        local px, py = p:getPosition()

        local colliders = world:queryRectangleArea(px +(40 * p.direction), py + 40, 10, 10)
        -- colliders etc. currently unused, but I assume you'll use them later?  
    end
    walk(dt)
end
```

You could refactor your `walk` function to not move *all* people, but rather only a single entity `p`. Then you could call `walk(p, dt)` inside the loop. You'd have to get rid of the loop in `walk` then.

Comment: thank you so much, now I understand. I just started learning and faced this problem.